# Run native ARM executable on Jelly Bean

Tags: security, android-ndk, adb

I am looking for methods to run native ARM executable on Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean). For example, compiling the classical C program

```
// hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

to ARMv7a executable, say `hello` using the Android NDK and then run it in Android shell. I have tried method suggested on the web such as pushing the executable to `/data/local` by

```
adb push hello /data/local
```

change permission to allow it to be executed by

```
adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/hello
```

and then invoke them in the shell using

```
adb shell /data/local/hello
```

The last step fails with error:

```
/data/local/hello: not found
```

but evidently the file is there. I suspect the problem is that Jelly Bean's shell does not allow one to execute *alien* binaries anymore. Can anyone confirm this and give me a solution?

Comment: This isn't a programming for Android question as near as I can see. I believe this would be of interest to hardcore Android users.

Comment: @Chahk Thanks. Yet, I don't think that it answered my original question. Ultimately, I would like to run programs like 'dd' by cross-compiling it or using ARM pre-built version. Now I recall of 'busybox' and 'kbox' which also install new binary on the system so I believe that there is no security issue here. I will check out those work to see how they did it.

Comment: @Chahk - Given that the stack overflow question is from October 2011, and is thus answering for an unspecified older version of Android, the answer for Jelly Bean *could* be different. The questioner really just wants someone to confirm if it is or not, which is a practical answerable question about Android.

Comment: @MarkBooth fair enough.  For the record, I did not vote to close. Would love to know the answer to this.

Comment: Are you able to call binaries using their path at all? Does `/system/bin/ls` work, for example?

Comment: you also have to face the problem that under android is hard to link libraries with this approach because you are not running your application under a VM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run a native ARM binary in Android you have to compile with **-static**.

The *libc* that you use to build (if using the standard ARM toolchain and not Android NDK) is different from Android's *libc* (bionic) and therefore when your binary intends to link dynamically to *libc* on target it will not because *libc* doesn't exist on target.

With the **-static** option you link in what you need from *libc* at build time and don't have to worry about linking things in dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Check that adb push is not dumping a "Permission denied" error. An check file's existence by running: adb shell ls /data/local

Since I updated to 4.0.4 I cannot access to /data/local but to /data/local/tmp, and this would explain the "Not found" error.

Comment: I solve the problem by installing Google's NDK stand-alone toolchain and recompile the source code with it. There should be some mysterious things that the toolchain does under the hood.